# Please help to beautify this connection-graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I have made a graph that shows connection and relations between nodes. Here is the example:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[length=3mm, width=2mm]}]
\foreach \b/\angle/\d [count=\a] in %
{Rec-A/23/black,%
Rec-B/8/black,%
Rec-C/14/black,%
Rec-D/24/black,%
Rec-E/32/black,%
Rec-F/3/black,%
Rec-G/11/black,%
Rec-H/6/black}{%
\draw (\a*360/8: 4cm) node [circle,thick, draw=\d, text width=10mm, align=center] (\a) {\b \\ \angle};}
%
%Straight lines
%
\draw[->] (1) to[out=10,in=35,loop] node[right, midway,inner sep=2pt] {16} ();
\draw[->] (3) to[out=135,in=160,loop] node[left,midway, inner sep=2pt] {8} ();
\draw[->] (4) to[out=155,in=185,loop] node[left,midway, inner sep=2pt] {33} ();
\draw[->] (5) to[out=220,in=250,loop] node[left,midway, inner sep=2pt] {18} ();
\draw[->] (6) to[out=255,in=280,loop] node[below, midway,inner sep=2pt] {7} ();
\draw[->] (7) to[out=300,in=325,loop] node[right, midway, inner sep=2pt] {4} ();
\draw[->] (8) to[out=345,in=10,loop] node[right, midway, inner sep=2pt] {3} ();
%
%Curved lines
%%
\draw [draw = black,
arrows={- Stealth [left, black,length=8pt,bend,line width=0pt]}]
%(1)AAD
%(2)CanP
%(3)CvHMS to
(3) edge [thick, draw=black, bend left=0] node [sloped, anchor=south, pos=0.2] {1} (2)
(3) edge [thick, draw=black, bend left=0] node [sloped, anchor=south, below, pos=0.2] {10} (4)
(3) edge [thick, draw=black, bend left] node [sloped, anchor=south, below, pos=0.15] {1} (5)
(3) edge [thick, draw=black, bend left=0] node [sloped, anchor=south, above, pos=0.1] {2} (8)
%(4)GIH
(4) edge [thick, draw=black, bend right] node [sloped, anchor=south, pos=0.1] {1} (2)
(4) edge [thick, draw=black, bend left=0] node [sloped, anchor=south, pos=0.2] {1} (3)
(4) edge [thick, draw=black, bend right=0] node [sloped, below, pos=0.2] {11} (5)
(4) edge [thick, draw=black, bend left] node [sloped, anchor=south, pos=0.1] {1} (6)
%(5)ImmH
(5) edge [thick, draw=black, bend left=0] node [sloped, anchor=south, pos=0.1] {2} (2)
(5) edge [thick, draw=black, bend right] node [sloped, below, pos=0.1] {2} (3)
(5) edge [thick, draw=black, bend left=0] node [sloped, anchor=south, pos=0.25] {14} (4)
(5) edge [thick, draw=black, bend left=0] node [sloped, anchor=south, pos=0.2] {7}(6)
%(6)RspH
(6) edge [thick, draw=black, bend right] node [sloped, anchor=south, pos=0.2] {5} (4)
(6) edge [bend left=0] node [sloped, anchor=south, pos=0.2] {4} (5)
%(7)UrgH
(7) edge [thick, bend left=0, draw=black] node [sloped, anchor=south, pos=0.1] {2} (4)
%(8)WgtMgt
(8) edge [thick, draw=black, bend left=0] node [sloped, below, pos=0.1] {} (3)
(8) edge [thick, draw=black, bend left=0] node [sloped, below, pos=0.1] {} (4)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the corresponding output looks like this:

[image: My_image]

Is there a way to make this more appealing / pep it up? Each node is a "Record-Module" which shows the total counts. The numbers over the arrows show the connections. I would also like to be able to program those curled arrows using loops and add custom numbers.

Sorry for this rather "vague" request.

Comment: Do the nodes need to be placed in that order in a circle? If you'd move the Rec-B node to the left of Rec-D no arrow would cross another one.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: So cool! I didn't notice that. I found the circular structure very pleasing to the eye.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This kind of questions is hard to answer, because everybody has different concepts of what is appealing. The following is my input:

I would bend all edges: the outer edges to the outside, so that they are aligned like a circle that connects all the nodes, and the inner edges towards the center of the diagram which helps to avoid overlapping edges.

I would further try to standardise the distance and position where the labels sit on the arrows. I tried to position them always at `pos=0.2` for the outer (shorter) edges and at `pos=0.1` for the inner (longer) edges. Of course, this will not result in exactly the same distance from the relevant node, but it still is a good approach, I think. I also tried to always place the label on this side of the corresponding arrow where this arrow has its harpoon-style arrow head. I only diverted from this rule in two cases where such placement would result in the label overlapping another edge.

I finally cleaned up the code a bit (but I kept the color defintion in the `\foreach` loop althout `black` is always default, since you might want to use this in your project somehow).

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[length=3mm, width=2mm]}]
\foreach \b/\angle/\d [count=\a] in {
    Rec-A/23/black,
    Rec-B/8/black,
    Rec-C/14/black,
    Rec-D/24/black,
    Rec-E/32/black,
    Rec-F/3/black,
    Rec-G/11/black,
    Rec-H/6/black%
}{
    \node[circle, thick, draw=\d, text width=10mm, align=center] (\a) at (\a*360/8: 4cm) {\b \\ \angle};
}
   
% Loops
\begin{scope}[thick, ->, every node/.append style={midway, inner sep=2pt}]
    \draw (1) to[out=10, in=35, loop] node[right] {16} (1);
    \draw (3) to[out=135, in=160, loop] node[left] {8} (3);
    \draw (4) to[out=155, in=185, loop] node[left] {33} ();
    \draw (5) to[out=220, in=250, loop] node[left] {18} ();
    \draw (6) to[out=255, in=280, loop] node[below] {7} ();
    \draw (7) to[out=300, in=325, loop] node[right] {4} ();
    \draw (8) to[out=345, in=10, loop] node[right] {3} ();
\end{scope}

% Curved lines
\begin{scope}[thick, >={Stealth[left, length=8pt, bend, line width=0pt]}, ->, every node/.append style={sloped}]
    % (1) AAD
    % (2) CanP
    % (3) CvHMS to
    \draw (3) to[bend left=15] node[above, pos=0.2] {1} (2);
    \draw (3) to[bend right=15] node[above, below, pos=0.2] {10} (4);
    \draw (3) to[bend left] node[above, above, pos=0.1] {1} (5);
    \draw (3) to[bend right=15] node[above, above, pos=0.1] {2} (8);
    % (4) GIH
    \draw (4) to[bend right] node[above, pos=0.1] {1} (2);
    \draw (4) to[bend left=15] node[above, pos=0.2] {1} (3);
    \draw (4) to[bend right=15] node[above, pos=0.2] {11} (5);
    \draw (4) to[bend left] node[below, pos=0.1] {1} (6);
    % (5) ImmH
    \draw (5) to[bend right=20] node[below, pos=0.1] {2} (2);
    \draw (5) to[bend right] node[above, pos=0.1] {2} (3);
    \draw (5) to[bend left=15] node[below, pos=0.2] {14} (4);
    \draw (5) to[bend right=15] node[above, pos=0.2] {7} (6);
    % (6) RspH
    \draw (6) to[bend right] node[below, pos=0.1] {5} (4);
    \draw (6) to[bend left=15] node[below, pos=0.2] {4} (5);
    % (7) UrgH
    \draw (7) to[bend right=15] node[below, pos=0.1] {2} (4);
    %(8)WgtMgt
    \draw (8) to[bend left=15] (3);
    \draw (8) to (4);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is looks so much better than mine. It's the small stuff that end up mattering so much to the eye.